# Moving itemize to the right margin of the page

Tags: align, lists, itemize

I am looking for this desired effect (hrule is to show the margins of the page):
[image]

As shown in the picture, I want the itemize environment to be moved to the right margin of the page (exactly like `\raggedleft` or `\hfill`).

The code I used for the picture is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\begin{document}
\hrule
\medskip

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=150mm, noitemsep, nolistsep]
    \item Text Here
    \item[] More Text Here
    \item[] This is the Longest Text
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The problem is if the longest text is made longer or shorter the list no longer ends at the right margin.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this, but would need to box the list environment. For this, [`varwidth`](//ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) provides a similarly-named environment that will shrink its width to the natural width of the content, up to some maximum.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,varwidth}

\begin{document}

\hrule
\medskip

\begin{itemize}[nosep]
  \item Text Here
  \item[] More Text Here
  \item[] This is the Longest Text
\end{itemize}

\bigskip

\hrule
\medskip

\mbox{}\hfill
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
  \begin{itemize}[nosep]
    \item Text Here
    \item[] More Text Here
    \item[] This is the Longest Text
  \end{itemize}
\end{varwidth}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A list environment is not appropriate to do this, but a  `tabular` environment can mimic easily a list, and it can be right-aligned easily with `\hfill` (1st list in the MWE).

You do not need to type each bullet in each cell of the left column, only once in the tabular header (2nd list)

Using `tabulary` you can set a width maximum for the list (instead of a minimum, as using columns like `p{5cm}`), so a column with only short items will be as narrow as possible, whereas one with some long items will have automatic line breaks to not exceed the limit. Also is easy with `tabulary` have items with  justification and hyphenation, or make the text ragged right (better for a narrow list), as well as hang indent the bullets (like in `itemize` lists) or align bullets with text to gain some space (compare last item in list 3rd and 4th).

[image: Mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabulary,array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

\hfill\begin{tabular}{ll@{}}
     \textbullet & Little \\
                 & Text  \\
      \textbullet  & Here end.\\ 
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\hfill\begin{tabular}{>{\textbullet\quad}l@{}}
    Text Here  \\
    More Text Here \\
    This is the Longest Text\\ 
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\hfill\begin{tabulary}{.35\linewidth}{@{}>{\textbullet\quad}J@{}}
    Text Here  \\
    More Text Here \\
  This is the longest \lipsum[1][1] \\ 
\end{tabulary}


\bigskip\hfill\begin{tabulary}{.35\linewidth}{@{\textbullet\quad}L@{}}
  Text Here  \\
  More Text Here \\
  This is the longest \lipsum[1][1] \\ 
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```